# Proof of Sequential Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

The theorem of sequential continuity states that:

> f: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a)$ $\forall$ sequences $x_n \rightarrow a$.

In the proof of the converse statement, i.e. suppose we know $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a)$ and we want to prove $f$ is continuous, it is written that

> (1) Suppose for a contradiction $f$ is not continuous, and suppose $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a)$ for all sequences $x_n \rightarrow a$.
>
> (2) Then $\exists \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\forall \delta>0, \exists x \in
>  (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(a)| \geq \epsilon$.
>
> (3) Choose $\delta = \dfrac{1}{n}$. Then $\exists x_n ∈ (a - \dfrac{1}{n}, a + \dfrac{1}{n})$ such that $|f(x_n) − f(a)| \geq \epsilon$. So $|x_n - a|<\dfrac{1}{n}$ $\forall n$ and therefore $x_n \rightarrow a$. But $f(x_n) \not\rightarrow f(a)$.

I can understand that from (2) is the negation of the definition of continuity which we assumed for a contradiction but I cannot understand how we get to $x_n \rightarrow a$ from $|x_n - a|<\dfrac{1}{n}$ $\forall n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *definition* of $x_n \to a$ is

$$\forall \varepsilon >0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n \ge N: |x_n -a| < \varepsilon $$

So pick $\varepsilon>0$ and note that there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}< \varepsilon$. This is a consequence of the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) of the real numbers, if you want to be precise, or a consequence of the fact that $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ in $\Bbb R$, if you covered that. I claim that this $N$ is as required, because for all $n \ge N$ we have $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N}$ so

$$|x_n -a| < \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$$

So the fact that $x_n \to a$ is an almost immediate consequence of $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$, really.

Comment: Yeah I get it, but I am still not sure we have $f(x_n) \not\rightarrow f(a)$ at the end. I think we suppose $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a)$ at the beginning.

Comment: @Thomas No, we supposed the negation of continuity and we chose $\varepsilon$ etc. Then this assumption gives us a sequence with $x_n \to a$, but for all $x_n$, $|f(x_n) - f(a)| \ge \varepsilon$, so $f(x_n) \not \to f(a)$: the distance never becomes smaller than $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0.$ By definition, $x_n \to a$ if there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N,$ we have $|x_n-a|<\epsilon.$ By the Archimedean property of real numbers, there exists $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon.$ But then $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N.$ Therefore,
$$
|x_n-a|<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon.
$$
for all $n\geq N.$

Answer (score 1):

Sequential continuity is in general a weaker statement than continuity, but is equivalent to continuity in first-countable spaces, that is, a space $X$ in which for every point $x\in X$, there exists a sequence $\{U_n\}$ of neighborhoods of $x$ such that for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists a positive integer $i$ with $U_i\subset U$.

For if $f$ is not continuous at $x\in X$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ such that for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, we have $f(U)\not\subset V$. Since $X$ is first-countable, there is a sequence $\{U_n\}$ of $x$ such that there exists a positive integer $i$ with $U_i\subset U$. But since $f(U_1)\not\subset V$, we may choose $x_1\in U_1$ such that $f(x_1)\notin V$. This yields a sequence $\{x_i\}$ which satisfies $x_i\to x$ but $f(x_i)\notin V$ for all $i$, so in particular $f(x_i)\not\to f(x)$.

Clearly $\mathbb R$ is a first-countable space, in particular being a metric space, so sequential continuity and continuity are equivalent.